# Using registered COM library in LINQPad

Tags: .net, activex, linqpad

... such as the Windows Image Acquisition library? In Visual Studio I would add a reference from the **Add References** dialog, but LINQPad only allows adding references to .NET assemblies.

I don't even need strongly typed objects (although it would be prefereable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a RCW assembly to reference the library. Use the [tlbimp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool to create an .NET assembly that provides wrappers to your COM objects. You can reference this assembly from LINQPad via Query Properties - Additional References.